# query with IIF statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am responsible for producing a set of name badges for an upcoming class reunion.  Have everything set up and have been able to produce the correct output for those attending the reunion.

What I want to do is place parenthesis around the maiden names of the married women attending the reunion.  Right now the maiden name is being displayed on the badge, but without parenthesis.

I have placed the following expression in the MaidenName field of the query I have written, but nothing is happening, at least this expression did not produce any error messages when I ran it.

```
IIf([MaidenName]="IsNull",[MaidenName]=" ",([MaidenName]=("("+[MaidenName]+")")))
```

When I entered the expression the first time the IsNull was without quotes.  When I ran the
the query the quotes were place around the IsNull statement.  The query ran, but there were no parenthesis around the maiden name on the output.

Comment: Could you show the whole query please?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably like to use the `IsNull()` function, and clean a little bit that `Iif` syntax:

```
IIf(IsNull([MaidenName]), " ", "(" & [MaidenName] & ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the SQL-native `is null` comparison instead of the `IsNull()` function. A SQL-native way will always be faster and more portable than a VBA function.

```
iif(MaidenName is null, '', ' (' & MaidenName & ')')
```

Plus I think it's easier to read.